# How to Redirect the Android app console output to a text box in WPF application using Android Debug Bride

Tags: c#, adb

I am a Newbee to ADB. My question can be divided into three parts. I was trying  to develop an application using WPF and android debug bridge.

1. I wanted to select an apk file
2. install this apk file and
3. run the apk file through this gui. (facing some heavy delay problems with redirecting output)                                                                                        4. as well as redirecting the output of this android app to my GUI in WPF  (Heavy delay)                                     Can anyone tell why this heavy delay, and does anyone have easy way of redirecting the output to my WPF application. Any Response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful to you anyway the first three answers are for others who want to create a similar application like,since you have tagged it for **c#** and **adb** i'll tell how to do it, normally you can execute Windows shell commands via `System.diagnostics.process.start("command");` right? so by integrating it with **adb** commands you accomplish what've been listed above

1. Select an apk file using `OpenFileDialog`then save the path in a
   string `path`
2. Run `System.diagnostics.process.start("adb install",path);`
3. use `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <package name of your apk>/<.Activity name>` inside the `System.diagnostics.process.start()`
4. I don't think you are using `adb shell logcat` in the shell,if you were there wont be any heavy delay,**(i mean it is not giving me any delay)** it could be that your application is not returning any logs or it can be the result of wrong filtering.